# Can anyone confirm I have the right understanding of static routing?

Tags: static

Sorry this question is really simple, but im taking my  CCNA and its really unclear to me in parts.

THis is how I absorbed it: Your connecting cable has an ip address for itself, and extensions of that address for both outgoing and incoming interfaces, .2, .212, .60 (any odd number.) When you configure static routes, the next hop in a path from point Router 1 to point Router 2, is the ip assigned to the outgoing interface of the nexthop router  (Router 3)...  So something like 11.145.0.2, Where 2 is this extension of that cable's IP address. Thanks this was not very clearly explained to me in the beginning.

Comment: A static route is a manually configured route (unlike a route learned from a routing protocol). Basically a route is: to reach network A go via next-hop B. (The router also does this: to reach next-hop B go via interface EthX). So when a packet destined to network A arrives, it follows the instruction given by the route. Hope this clears things up a bit.

Answer (score 1):

Any device (regardless of router, end user device, phone, switch, wireless security camera, etc.) has a routing table (assuming it has a functional network software stack).

If it it has a normal IPv4 or IPv6 network configuration, it will also have a route table. That table is simply a list of route configurations that the device has learned/been manually given/has by default.

The concept of a 'route' is simply a configuration of "in order to reach the desired network, send traffic via the configured interface or IP address".

For example, a device might be given a 'default route' configuration via a Dynamic Host Configuration Protocol (DHCP) service when the device connects to the network. The DHCP service tells the device what its IP address, Subnet Mask and default route or default gateway configuration should be. It might be something like IP address 10.10.10.3, subnet mask 255.255.255.0, and default route of 0.0.0.0/0 via 10.10.10.1

That is a route that was configured via a dynamic configuration protocol. Devices like routers can also learn routes via a 'dynamic routing protocal' such as OSPF, BGP, ISIS, etc. Basically that is a protocol that routers and some other network devices use to share their route table information with other routers or network devices so they can talk successfully to each other and to the rest of the network/internet without massive amounts of ongoing manual configuration.

Devices that have a valid IP address configuration will also have a 'connected' route by default because that valid IP address configuration tells the device that it can reach itself via its own interface (of course) and that it can reach any other device in its defined network (according to the subnet mask or CIDR configuration) via the same interface since that network is on a connected interface.

To get to your actual question... a Static Route is simply a manually configured route configuration that the administrator of a given device (router, computer, phone, game console, etc.) has added to the device network configuration to define how to reach a desired network via a desired gateway/router address or a desired interface.

For example, the computer mentioned before that was given a DHCP address configuration of 10.10.10.3/24 (that is CIDR notation version of Subnet Mask 255.255.255.0) and the default route of 0.0.0.0/0 via 10.10.10.1 might encounter a situation where the administrator wants to reach a separate network that is only reachable via a special router that is not part of the DHCP configuration. They could manually (statically) add a route configuration such as 172.16.30.0/24 via 10.10.10.50 which means that the network 172.16.30.0 with subnet mask 255.255.255.0 is reachable by sending traffic to the device with IP address 10.10.10.50 configured on it. The device with 10.10.10.50 on it is presumably a router and should deliver traffic to the proper destination IP address in the network 172.16.30.0/24 when the computer sends traffic to it.

The destination device in the network 172.16.30.0/24 will also need to have appropriate configuration to know how to send a reply back to the computer with IP address 10.10.10.3, otherwise it will simply try to reply via its default route, which might or might now know how to reach the 10.10.10.0/24 network.

Long story short: a static route is simply a manually configured route as opposed to a dynamically learned or directly connected route. It is not learned from any other device, nor via assumption from the devices own local interface configuration and must be manually configured by the administrator of the device.